# Show Value only for Middle Row in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an expression for subtotal

> sum(Fields!a.Value,"rowgroup")

But the issue is that the subtotal repeats on all the rows within the group,  whereas I want the value to be shown only in 1 row i.e. middle row. I believe the best way to achieve this would be using an expression in Text Box Properties 'Show or hide based on an expression' but I am not sure how to write an expression which shows value only for middle row in a given group.

Example: -

> Using Expression that I have

```
Column A          Column B           Column C
ABC                  20                 70
BCD                  30                 70
EFG                  20                 70
```

> Output that I am trying to Achieve (2 examples)

```
Column A          Column B           Column C
    ABC                  20                 
    BCD                  30             70
    EFG                  30                 

Column A                Column B           Column C
    ABC                  20                 
    BCD                  30             
    EFG                  20   
    GHI                  10                  100
    IJK                  10
    XYZ                  10
```

Comment: just an idea.. conditionally set the value of the column perhaps? Something like..     = iif(cint(countrows(yourdataset) /2 )= rownumber("yourdataset"),fields!coulmnc.value,"")  haven't tested it.. just an idea..

Comment: @Harry This would work only for even row count and would return blank for odd row count.

Comment: for odd number, you could round up the numbers.. so for a count of 3 rows (for example).. divided by 2 = 1.5.. rounding up, you would get 2.. so display on row 2 ??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand and assume your requierement, In below image left hand side shows original data and right hand side shows desired result

[image]

Now how did I do that?

1. First I create a normal table and add all the fields Id, Col A and Col B just like image above left hand one.
2. Then I first group by ID (make sure Parent Group and not normal Group). when I do that I get output something like below

[image]
[image]

3. Then when you add Total to Details Group you will see

[image]
[image]

That's it do some renaming and you are good to go. BTW for me Column B is number data type (Integer)

Comment: I am trying to get totals at a column level and not a row level. Example for ID1 Value '150' should be next to 30 in a 'column C'